# Starting Outlook automatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

How can I get Outlook to start whenever I start my Windows 10 computer?

Comment: Summary: Win+R and type shell:appsfolder to open a folder where you will find outlook. Then Win+R and type shell:startup to open a folder where you have to drag/drop the outlook to create a shortcut.

Answer (score 166):

You should be able to add a shortcut to Outlook in the Startup folder.  To open the Startup folder:

**Using the Run dialog:**

- Bring up Run dialog <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `shell:startup`

[image]

Copy the shortcut to Outlook to the Startup folder:

1. Right click on the Outlook shortcut from your start menu
2. Select `Open file location`
3. Copy the shortcut for Outlook to the Startup folder

Comment: BTW: two issues in your answer: 1. We dont Right click, we have to Left click to see Run. 2. Instead of the first bullets, we can also hit All Programs/Startup then right click and 'open'; and you might want to update the second (1) to what I mentioned in my answer

Comment: @killjoy Right-clicking Start (== Win+X) also has “Run”. There is no “All Programs” in Windows 10. The “Startup” folder is also not visible even if present. Remember: This question is specifically about Windows 10.

Comment: Updated.. hope that helps.

Comment: type `shell:startup`, not `start shell:startup` ( you explain in details how to bring up Run Dialog, not the same for the "command promt", so, or you do the same level of explanation for everything, or remove the command prompt

Comment: @Serge - thanks, I've cleaned up the formatting to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: +1 for the tip for opening the startup folder by only one command.

Comment: I'm on a company computer and I cannot access the startup folder (and many others) due to restrictions, is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 18):

On Windows 10:

1. Go to Start
2. Scroll down until you find Outlook
3. Right-click on Outlook
4. Click `More` then click `Go to File Location`
5. Copy the shortcut
6. Paste the shortcut into the Startup folder: `Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
7. That's it.

Answer (score 7):

## The short one-liner

1. Right-click your Start button and choose **Windows PowerShell**.
2. Copy and paste the following command and hit Enter:

```
cp(gci([Environment]::GetFolderPath(22)) -r -fi *Outlook*.lnk).FullName ([Environment]::GetFolderPath(7))
```

Outlook should start next time you log in.

#### The expanded version of the command

```
Copy-Item (Get-ChildItem ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("CommonStartMenu")) -Recurse -Filter "*Outlook*.lnk").FullName ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Startup"))
```

Wildcards are used when searching for the Outlook shortcut because it goes by different names depending on Office version (e.g. *Microsoft Outlook 2010*, *Outlook*).

Answer (score 4):

To build on @Glenn's answer for Win7+Outlook 2010:

As easy as this is supposed to  be, I tried various other methods (Windows 7); stupid MS removed the ability to set this from within Outlook (2010); and the shortcuts in Start menu did not have the 'open file location' option, even the one under 'All Programs/MS Office' - it was only after I did a "search" for outlook by clicking Start and typing in search window, that it showed this option ! What a harrowing hour for a measly shortcut !!

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add a comment to @glenn's answer, but the site doesn't allow. So, here is an alternative:

1. For any installed application, you can 'shell:appsfolder' in the Run window (Win+R), then find your app, and while holding mouse right button drag it to the startup folder, and choose 'Create Shortcut Here'.
2. As Glenn has already mentioned, you can open the startup folder by running 'shell:startup' in the Run window.
3. For any random executable file, you can either

   - If you have the shortcut file already, copy and paste in the startup folder.
   - Find it in Windows Start menu, right click and choose 'open file location'.
   - When the app is running, go to Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), find it in the list of running apps, right click and chose 'open file location', the rest is the same.

Answer (score 2):

In order to add any program to startup when Windows starts simply copy the Shortcut to the Startup Folder

Open the command window (Win+R) and enter

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

This will open the Startup location in the File Explorer. Next from the Start Menu right click the program you want to have startup (Outlook in this case) and select `More->Open File Location` this will open the location of the program Shortcut. Finally copy and paste the shortcut into the Startup Folder.

Copied from Microsoft's article [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-start-an-Office-program-when-you-turn-on-your-computer-4A42ED45-C064-47B6-B497-119C870F7BAB)